# Problema com conflito entre IIS e Xampp

Tags: apache, iis, xampp, localhost

Fiz a cagada de instalar o IIS e agora está dando conflito no localhost:80, ja desinstalei, desativei os componentes e fiz tudo que achei na internet, mas ele permanece no domínio, alguem sabe como posso tira-lo de vez? Ou mudar a porta do Apache de maneira que continue funcionando? Não quero ter que formatar o pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abra o arquivo **httpd.conf** (apache/conf/httpd.conf) no bloco de notas e altere as linhas:

> Listen 80

e

> ServerName localhost:80

substituindo o 80 por uma nova porta, que não está em uso – como 89, por exemplo.

Teste entrando em:

> http://localhost:89